# Python remove the single quotes from the dictionary

Tags: python, postgresql

I have following PostgreSQL query

```
data = {'token':"123",'kart_user':"tablename"}
select_stmt = "SELECT * FROM %(kart_user)s WHERE token = %(token)s"
self.cur.execute(select_stmt, data)
result = self.cur.fetchone()
```

In the select  query `%(kart_user)s` is represent in the form of single quotes
My question is how can i remove the quotes from the same query??.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole *point* of using SQL parameters is to prevent data being interpreted as SQL objects or syntax. You can't use SQL parameters to name tables; you can only use SQL parameters for data.

You'll have to interpolate table names separately. This does means you run a risk of opening up your code to SQL injections; I'd test the table name against a list of known tablenames if this is sourced from user input.

```
assert data['kart_user'] in known_tables
select_stmt = "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE token = %(token)s".format(data['kart_user'])
self.cur.execute(select_stmt, data)
```